# Node.js os library not giving desired output

Tags: node.js, node-modules

```
console.log('Starting App');

const fs = require ('fs');
const os = require ('os');

var user = os.userInfo();


fs.appendFileSync('message.txt',  'Hello  ${user.username}!');
```

Comment: output : Hello  ${user.username}!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not `os`, the problem is that you're not using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), which should be wrapped with backticks (`), and not by single quotes.

```
fs.appendFileSync('message.txt',  `Hello  ${user.username}!`);
//                                ` instead of '
```